# EC2 pycurl installed but not found

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I install pycurl

```
>$ /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install pycurl --global-option="--with-openssl" --upgrade

/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py:230: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option.
  cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.6.tar.gz (222 kB)
Skipping wheel build for pycurl, due to binaries being disabled for it.
Installing collected packages: pycurl
    Running setup.py install for pycurl ... done
Successfully installed pycurl-7.43.0.6
```

Then checks installation, it does not appear

```
>$ /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip show pycurl

 WARNING: Package(s) not found: pycurl
```

And of course any code wanting to use the lib does not find it (celery, for instance)

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to another question (sorry, I can't find the link).
This worked for me:

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include 
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
pip install pycurl==7.43.0.5 --global-option="--with-openssl" --upgrade
```